# Firebase: URL Rewrites/Redirect with URL Variables

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I want to access example.com/folder/value1/value2/ on a Firebase hosted website and load content from example.com/folder/index.html?var1=value1&var2=value2 while keeping the new URLs (not redirecting to the .html page with variables in it).

I have tried the following but it returns a 404 error:

```
rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/folder/:value1*/:value2*/",
    "destination": "/folder/index.html?var1=:value1&var2=:value2"
  }
```

Any ideas if this is possible in Firebase? Similar to htaccess rewrites?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Hosting rewrites only rewrite the file path, not query parameters. It is not possible to use captures in rewrites (only in redirects), and the `destination` must be an exact path to a deployed static file.

Comment: So I should use **redirects** in my example above? That will redirect someone accessing example.com/folder/value1/value2/ to example.com/folder/index.html?var1=value1&var2=value2 but will have the final URL in the address bar? i.e. there's no possibility to have the address bar url show as example.com/folder/value1/value2/.

Comment: any news about it?